# Txt, XML or database for backup and restore purpose?

Tags: android, file, backup

I'm trying to backup & restore SMS and contacts informations and wondering about the way to do that. Keeping in mind that:

1. I want a lightweight app
2. Regarding to reading/writting delays and mechanisms specific to each files type
3. I'm looking for the easiest way to do this backup and restore process.

Which one of `.txt` , `.xml` and SQLite `.db` files will fit my needs? Or there is another efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

u can use sqLiteDatabase.which is very easy to use.all the things r handled with cursor.which means at a time indicating a single row in a database.check this link:
 http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/working-with-the-sqlite-database-cursors-t319.html